# Do I need the underlying Vector software to edit the image-Im a rank amateur at all of this!

Tags: image-editing

I had my company logo created by Vistaprint, but now I need to make color and size edits. I think Vistaprint "owns" the vector file, so I believe I will need to hire my own designer and ask for the file(s). Once I receive the file(s) is there a "simple" way for an amateur like me to do edits, or will I need to purchase/learn (ugh!) illustrator or another complex software program???

Any direction would be most appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to make *changes* to your logo frequently...

Comment: You might be able to do basic color changes or something on paint, depending on what you are considering, but I would plan to work with a designer or have software. Spend a little thinking about all the changes you need and have a designer create all the versions in one go, it'll be cheaper that way 

Answer (score 1):

In 99.9% of cases, you need vector software to make changes to vector graphics. If it's an SVG file, you could theoretically make the changes in a text editor but I wouldn't recommend it except for the simplest of cases (or in really weird edge cases).

As for what software you'd need to use, it doesn't have to be Illustrator. Inkscape is a free software that can edit SVG, PDF, and Illustrator files. The learning curve is fairly low for simple things like changing colors, so I wouldn't stress too much about hiring anyone.

If you are unable to get the file, you will need to rebuild it manually. If you have a particularly low level of patience, hire someone. I would recommend actually learning to use Inkscape or Illustrator though - you never know when the skill could come in handy.